# Double Click on table row [Material-Table]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, double-click, material-table

I am using React Material-Table (https://material-table.com/). There is a property onRowClick, but I need on row Double Click which is missing in the documentation. Hover on the row will work too. Can someone help with this please?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

```
<MTableBodyRow
    {...props}
    onDoubleClick={e => { // <--- this is how you can catch DoubleClick on row
        alert("Make row editable");
    }}
/>
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit #SO-material-onclick-edit]